Converses to Cartan's Theorem B
Here is a phrasing of some Cartan Theorem B statements:

Consider the following conditions:

$X$ is a {Stein manifold, affine scheme, coherent analytic subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^n$, contractible subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$}.
$\mathcal{F}$ is a {coherent, quasi-coherent, coherent, locally constant} sheaf (of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules) on $X$.
The sheaf cohomology $\operatorname{H}^p(X,\mathcal{F})$ is zero for $p\geqslant1$.

Then (1) + (2) $\implies$ (3).

Here this statement applies to four geometric contexts: {complex-analytic, complex-algebraic, real-analytic, smooth}. In all of these, a "sharpness" statement also holds:

Given arbitrary $X$, if every sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ (of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules) that satisfies (2) also satisfies (3), then $X$ satisfies (1).

(For the two complex contexts, this is "classical"; for the real-analytic case, I believe this should be covered in Cartan's paper "Variétés analytiques réelles et variétés analytiques complexes" but I should check this; for the smooth case, this is quasi-folklore.)
Question. For the four contexts above, is the remaining implication known to be true? i.e. is the statement

Let $X$ satisfy (1); if an arbitrary sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ (of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules) satisfies (3) then it satisfies (2).

true?
I assume this should be false, at least in the smooth case, given the existence of e.g. injective sheaves that are not locally constant, and I think in the complex-algebraic case it's also false (thanks to skyscraper sheaves) but I'm not so sure about the other cases.
Ideally an answer would consist of four "yes/no" answers with some references, but I'd be happier with some partial answers  than with no answers at all :-)

The two top answers to this question don't contradict each other, because the second answer changes the $\mathcal O_X$-module structure by replacing $M$ by $f_*f^{-1}M$. The latter is quasi-coherent, even if $M$ is not.

ok, so skyscraper sheaves do give a negative answer for the algebraic case! great :) I'll update the question

For (4), there are finite CW complexes $X$ which are not contractible, but such that $H^q(X, \mathcal{F})$ vanishes for all (finite rank) locally constant sheaves $\mathcal{F}$. Specifically, take $X$ to have one vertex $v$; four edges $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ from $v \to v$, and four pentagonal $2$-cells with boundaries $b^{-1} a^{-1} b^2 a$, $c^{-1} b^{-1} c^2 b$, $d^{-1} c^{-1} d^2 c$ and $a^{-1} d^{-1} a^2 d$. We easily compute that this complex is connected and has vanishing cohomology, so the trivial locally constant sheaf on $X$ has vanishing cohomology. The fundamental group of $X$ is Higman's group.
Locally constant sheaves (of rank $N$, over $k$) come from maps $\pi_1(X) \to \text{GL}_N(k)$, and Higman's group has no non-constant maps to $\text{GL}_N(k)$ for any $k$ or $N$ (see Remark 2 in Tao's blogpost), so the only locally constant sheaves on $X$ are trivial ones, and thus have vanishing cohomology.
But the fundamental group (Higman's group) is nontrivial, so this is not contractible.
I think you should be able to thicken $X$ to a $5$-fold by standard tricks, but I didn't think through the details of this.

If, on the other hand, "local system" doesn't mean "finite rank", then $\tilde{H}^q(X, \mathcal{F})=0$ for all $q$, where $X$ is a CW complex, implies $X$ contractible. Suppose that $X$ is such a CW complex. Since $\tilde{H}^0$ with constant coefficients vanishes, $X$ is connected.
I next claim that $X$ is simply connected (this is the only place that I'll use a non-trivial local system). Let $G = \pi_1(X)$. Let $\mathbb{Z}G$ be the free abelian group on $G$, so an element of $\mathbb{Z}G$ is of the form $\sum a_g g$, where the sum is finite. Let $U \subset \mathbb{Z}G$ be $\{ \sum a_g g : \sum a_g = 0 \}$, so we have a short exact sequence of $G$-modules
$$0 \to U \to \mathbb{Z}G \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
where the last map sends $\sum a_g g$ to $\sum a_g$. This induces a short exact sequence of locally constant sheaves, which I'll denote by the underlined versions of the $G$-modules.
Since $H^1(X, \underline{U})$ vanishes, $H^0(X, \underline{\mathbb{Z}G}) \to H^0(X, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$ must be surjective. Now, $H^0(X, \underline{\mathbb{Z}G})$ is the invariants
$$(\mathbb{Z}G)^G = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} \sum_{g \in G} g & G \ \text{finite} \\ 0 & G \ \text{infinite} \end{cases}.$$
So the image of $H^0(X, \underline{\mathbb{Z}G})$ in $H^0(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is
$$\begin{cases} |G| \mathbb{Z} & G \ \text{finite} \\ 0 & G \ \text{infinite} \end{cases}.$$
We see that the only way for the map to be surjectiveis if $|G|=1$, so $X$ is simply connected, as claimed.
Now, using the vanishing of $H^q(X, \underline{Z})$ for higher $q$, we see that all the reduced cohomology groups of $X$ vanish. So, by the universal coefficient theorem, all of the homology groups vanish. So the map $X \to \text{point}$ induces an isomorphism on all homology groups, and $X$ is simply connected. From Corollary 4.33 in Hatcher, that means that the map $X \to \text{point}$ is a homotopy equivalence, so $X$ is contractible.
PS: The reason that I kept saying that $X$ was a CW complex is because that is the assumption in Hatcher.

This assumes local systems have finite rank.

@DanPetersen True. I was wondering whether I should address the other possibility. I believe that then we do get contractibility, but I need some time to check details. Or maybe someone else will. :)

Yes, it's OK, see  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472300/smooth-analogue-of-cartans-theorem-b

@Donu The version of homology Whitehead theorem that I know says that if $f:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ and on homology with all possible local coefficients, then it is a weak equivalence. This doesn't seem to apply here since we don't have a $\pi_1$-equivalence. I actually don't know if there exists a noncontractible space with vanishing higher cohomology for all local coefficients.

@DanPetersen Good point. I may have skimmed my reference too quickly. Will check again.

@DonuArapura Okay, I added the details.

Also pinging @DanPetersen

Nice argument David.

@DavidESpeyer Great. I linked my answer back to yours. Hopefully this won't create a strange loop.

This is a very thorough answer, but unless I'm mistaken, isn't this concerning the statement (2)+(3)=>(1) ? I'm very happy to see that this "sharpness" condition is actually true as long as we add the important hypothesis that "locally constant" means "locally constant of possibly infinite rank", but my question was about (1)+(3)=>(2).

@DavidESpeyer do you agree that the question answered here is slightly different? if so, I'll make a new question specifically to give this answer a proper venue, because it's something that I wanted to know anyway and would love to be able to cite!
